# fork/exec aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: exec format error

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I have a makefile which states

```
CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOARCH=arm64 GO111MODULE=on go build -mod=vendor -ldflags "$(GO_BUILDINFO)" -o bin/victoria-metrics-arm64 ./app/victoria-metrics
```

I have installed aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc binary like

```
mkdir aarch64-toolchain
cd aarch64-toolchain/
wget http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/6.5-2018.12/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-6.5.0-2018.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz
tar -Jxvf gcc-linaro-6.5.0-2018.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz
```

and exported it to Path variable

Output of **uname -a** command gives

```
Linux prom 4.14.0-115.2.2.el7a.aarch64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 28 22:05:51 UTC 2018 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Now I am getting error as

```
CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOARCH=arm64 GO111MODULE=on go build -mod=vendor -ldflags "-X 'github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/lib/buildinfo.Version=-20190716-133242-heads-master-0-gfb14f23'" -o bin/victoria-metrics-arm64 ./app/victoria-metrics
# runtime/cgo
fork/exec /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: exec format error
make: *** [victoria-metrics-arm64] Error 2
```

Please help me with the solution. I am stuck from a long time

Comment: You are on aarch64, yet you installed compiler for x86_64 that allows you to cross compile for aarch64. Just install gcc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KamilCuk. If I use CC=gcc then it works for me but if I have to use CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc for aarch64, are there any steps to make it run. Thanks for quick response

Comment: This is unclear. Why "you have to"? You _are on_ aarch 64 architecture. `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` is a cross-compiler. Think about it. Let's start from the top. There is a `x86_64-linux-gcc` compiler. It is written in C. It compiles code for x86_64 architecture. It was compiled using itself, but an older version, then compiled with itself. OK. So there is `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` compiler. It is written in C. It generates code for `aarch64` architecture. Then you compile `aarch-linux-gnu-gcc` with `gcc`. It's a compiler compiled for x86_64 architecture that generates code for arch64.

Comment: The term "cross-compiling" is compiling for _another_ architecture that you are on. If you want to cross-compile, then compile on x86_64 architecture for the aarch64 architecture. If you compile on aarch64 code for aarch64, that's like a normal compiling, it's just `gcc` on that architecture. You get "exec: format error", because the program is compiled for x86_64 architecture. And you try to run it on aarch64. They are incompatible. On a machine instruction level, the assembly code of two architectures are incompatible. So you get an error. What more do you want? What is your question?

Comment: I got your point @KamilCuk. I understood that if I have aarch64 then I should use CC=gcc as cross-compiler and for x86_64, I need to use CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try pure Go build for ARM. It is implemented recently in VictoriaMetrics and became the default for ARM. It has no cgo deps, so it can be built without C toolchain. See https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md#arm-build